# Why is the Comments Plugin shifting to the right?

Tags: php, facebook-comments

All of sudden today the comments plugin is out of its inteneded position, and it has shifted to the right thus creating inconvience. How do i fix it?

I have already tried updating to the latest code or whatever you wana call it.

Please help, how is  the problem gone be fixed.

example url is http://apne.tv/episodes/episodes/181/Diya-Aur-Baati-Hum.html

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Added this to my page/site CSS:

```
.fb_iframe_widget iframe {position:relative; left:0px;}
```

Seems to solve my problem. I think the issue seems to has resolved itself though.